# Why are delimited continuation primitives named "shift" and "reset"?

Tags: scala, continuations, delimited-continuations

I think I understand (in general) what `shift` and `reset` mean. However I do not understand why they are named so ? What do `shift` and `reset` as Delimited Continuation primitives have to do with "shift" and "reset" words in English?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They're called so because of the way they are implemented (in general).

Quoted from [**Direct Implementation of Shift and Reset in the MinCaml Compiler**](http://pllab.is.ocha.ac.jp/~asai/papers/tr09-1.pdf)

> By interpreting a program using the
>   continuation semantics, we can regard
>   the state of the program as a
>   continuation stack. Then, `reset` can be
>   thought of as marking the continuation
>   stack, and `shift` capturing the
>   continuation stack up to the nearest
>   mark created by `reset`. Here is the
>   overview of the implementation:
>
> - When calling `reset`, set a **reset mark** to the stack
> - When calling `shift` `(fun k -> M)`, **move** a part of the stack frames up to
>     the nearest reset mark to the heap
> - When calling a continuation `k`, set a **reset mark** to the stack and copy the
>     corresponding frames from the heap to
>     the stack top.
>
> A reset mark is inserted when `k` is
>   called, because captured continuations
>   are executed in an empty continuation.

Comment: It's worth noting that Scala's delimited continuations aren't implemented in such a direct way - they can't be.  The JVM doesn't expose stack manipulation primitives.

Comment: In contrast, Scheme-48 does allow for a direct implementation (Gasbichler/Sperber), as does any language that exposes the call stack, like Squeak Smalltalk.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's the way Danvy & Filinski called those two operators in [the first paper where they exposed that model of continuation-passing style](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.8753) (see also [here](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=91622)), and it is what Scala implements.

The implementation in Scala is described in [this other paper](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/149136/). The reference therein to Danvy & Filinski is clear:

> In this paper, we study the addition of control operators shift and reset to this language framework, which together implement static delimited continuations (Danvy and Filinski 1990, 1992)